# ATmega328P 16MHz or higher clock output on CLKO pin

Tags: atmega, frequency, clock, programming, fuse-bits

I need a high frequency clock (16MHz or higher) to drive OV7670 camera module, and I want my ATmega328P to be source of that clock. I'm using the `CLKO` pin since I can't get such high frequencies from PWM.

I programmed the lower fuse bits (0xBF - 8MHz+ external crystal osc., `PB0` used to output clock) so it outputs its clock from quartz on `PB0` pin. The problem is that if I drive my ATmega with 16MHz quartz, I get 8MHz output. If I use 20MHz quartz, then I get 4MHz output on `PB0`. The highest clock I get is from 12MHz quartz - then I get 12MHz on `PB0`.

It's quite strange since frequency goes like opposite direction. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Verify your fuse bits settings:

- You should choose full swing crystal oscillator, that is `CKSEL3...1` should be 011.
- Then you can choose "*Crystal Oscillator, slowly rising power*", that is `CKSEL0` is 1 and `SUT1..0` is 11.
- You selected 8MHz - why? If you use 16 MHz thats not the right setting.
- `CLKO` pin will output system clock - that can be divided by the prescaler.
- See chapter 9.12.2 in the datasheet. Register `CLKPR` should have bits `CLKPS3...0` set to 0, so it gives prescaler value of 1.
- That is make sure the fuse bit `CKDIV8` is not enabled, as this will divide the clock by 8.

So it is more probably that 0xB7 is the correct settings, not the 0xBF. See [this calculator](http://eleccelerator.com/fusecalc/fusecalc.php?chip=atmega328p)